# Using PHP to execute `git pull` command - deploy with github

Tags: php, deployment, ssh, github

I have been able to connect a local repository to a private Github repo (using the Github for Windows GUI), which should then automatically deploy to a development server. Everything is running smoothly until I make an attempt at the following:

```
<?php `git pull -f`;
```

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh

Once I commit then sync/push through Github for Windows, this script is supposed to call the Linux command 'git pull -f'. I have used a SSH key without a passphrase in an effort to make it easier but to no avail. However, if I were to execute the command via command-line, everything works perfectly.

File & folder permissions are set to 777 throughout the root directory (including the /.git folder),  which is what I thought was the reason for not being able to see updates when viewing the website I am developing.

If anyone has had a similar experience with this I would be grateful for a solution.

Note: I have searched high and low on SO and elsewhere on the web for a potential fix to this but any resources will be met with open arms.

Thanks,

Comment: no errors, just no visible results

Comment: And you're sure it's not actually working? Try ``echo `git pull -f`;``.

Comment: Might also be useful to do `echo \`git pull -f 2>&1\``; do make sure you see output on stderr

Comment: your php might be running under different system user (`SYSTEM` for example), while all git configuration is only available for your user. Does running this script from command line (`php.exe deploy.php`) work?

Comment: Cheers for the helo guys, sorry I couldn't get back to this until now.
@minitech I have tried this (and also `git pull 2>&1`), within the PHP file and also directly in command line but to no avail. Also tried stderr() but nothing is happening.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Yes, running `git pull 2>&1` from command line does work but I need it to run from the PHP script in order to automate the deployment to the server. I have also tried changing to the root user with the Linux command `su` but that won't be feasible through a PHP script from what I can see.

Comment: This might possibly be a problem with my WebHook URL on the private Github repo. I have the file with the bash command in the root directory ('public_html/') and the WebHook reads "http://project.dev.domain.co.uk/github.php". Can anyone confirm if this is/isn't correct? Thanks